# Editable combobox only in PHP or HTML

Tags: php, html, combobox

Here is my table:

```
</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Test System: </td>
<td><select name="TestSystem">
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("select name from test_system");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<option value="" selected> </option>';
echo '<option value="' .$row['name'] .'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>       
</td>
```

but I want it to be editable. It means, for example that the user can write first letter(for example "A"), and he can see all the options starting with the letter "A".
Is there anyway to do this without any frameworks/JavaScript? Only in PHP or HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right the short answer is: No

Thats how you could do it with Javasript (jQueryUI): 
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Well, without JS your limited to the standard HTML elements and their functions. As the HTML-select-element does not support an autocomplete function (at least i dont know) the only way to add this functionality would be to use Javascript. If anybody knows a different way let me know.